# Question regarding $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

We have the following statement:

> Prove that if $a=qb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$ then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$

Notation: $D_{a,b}$ stands for $\{x\in\Bbb{Z}\mid x\mid a,\;x\mid b\}$. So we need to prove $D_{a,b}=D_{b,r}$.

We prove $\subseteq$: for all $x\in D_{a,b}$, $x\mid a$ and $x\mid b$, then $x\mid qb+r$ and $x\mid b$ and $x\mid b$. So $x\mid qb+r$ and $x\mid (-q)b$ and $x\mid b$, then $x\mid(qb+r-qb)$ and $x\mid b$, hence $x\mid r$ and $x\mid b$, thus $x\in D_{b,r}$.

The same for the converse.

---

But then it says:

*We can show not only that the greatest common divisors are equal but that the set of all common divisors of $a$ and $b$ is the same as the set of all common divisors of $b$ and $r$, so the greatest of each set is the same.*

**It is asking to prove that $\max(D_{a,b})=\max(D_{b,r})$? How can we prove it? Why is it important?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That sentence says that $D_{a,b}=D_{b,r}$ and that therefore $\max D_{a,b}=\max D_{b,r}$.

Comment: Thank you José Carlos! My question is about the italic words, not the main property.

Comment: I know. My answer was about that.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a proof for if $A=B$ then $\max A=\max B$? In what context can we prove it? I hope only using elementary theory numbers.

Comment: If two things are equal, and if you apply the same operation to both of them, then you get the same thing. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The part in italics basically means that if $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$, then all common factors of a and b are the same as all the common factors of b and r, less than the gcd.

For example, Take numbers 48 and 104. $104=2\cdot 48 +8$. Here, $a=104,b=48,r=8$. So according the the sentence in italics, $\gcd (48,104)=\gcd(48,8)=8 $ and all common factors of 48 and 104:$1,2,4,8(D_{a,b})$ are the same as all common factors of 48 and 8:$1,2,4,8(D_{r,b})$

You can prove both the gcd and the prime factor part by splitting the 2 gcds into their prime factors and equating them. It is in fact quite easy.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Your example is great.