# Prove that if $A=B$ then $\max A=\max B$

Tags: order-theory, solution-verification

> Prove if $A=B$ then $\max A=\max B$.

---

(It follows from [Question regarding $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556294/question-regarding-gcda-b-gcdb-r)).

What I have done:

I will assume that $A$ and $B$ are equipped with a partial order $\leq$.

Let $\max A=a=\{x\in A\mid a\leq x\to x=a\}$ be the maximum element of $A$. Since $x\in A$, by hipothesis, $x\in B$, and so $a\leq x$ for all $x\in B$. Calling $a=b$ we have that $b\leq x$, so $x=b$. We have shown $\max A\subseteq\max B$, the same idea for the converse.

Is it correct?

Comment: you can just switch A and B in the definition of max, and get equality immediately.

Comment: Note that not every partial order has a maximum element. For example consider $A = B = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual ordering. Also your definition of $\operatorname{max}(A)$ is incorrect and self-referential. The correct definition should be: $\operatorname{max}(A) = a$ iff $\forall x \in A(x \le a)$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri in my book it says that an element $m\in A$ is **maximal** iff for all $x\in A$, if $m\leq x$ then $x=m$. Didn't I write the same definition on my question?

Comment: Why the negative votes? I have shown my work, why?

Comment: @manooooh, oh, I thought you meant maximum. But then, still there are posets with no maximal elements, the same example in my previous quote works. Also in your proof you are setting an element of $\max A$ equal to $\max A$, which is self-referential and in contradiction with axioms of set theory.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri oh, thank you. What would be a correct proof so?

Comment: @zwim, As the author is trying to prove that $\max$ is a function on the class of posets, what you suggest does not work.

Comment: Technically, what I am trying to prove is "higher". I suppose that is equal to "maximum", i.e. $\max$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = B$ be posets with the same order. Then pick some $a \in \operatorname{maximals}(A)$. Since $A = B$, we have $a \in B$. Now let $x \in B$. Since $A = B$ we have $x \in A$ and so by the fact that $a \in \operatorname{maximals}(A)$ we have $x \le a$. Now since $x \in B$ was arbitrary, we conclude $a \in \operatorname{maximals}(B)$. We have proven $\operatorname{maximals}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{maximals}(B)$. The converse is similar.

Comment: Thank you! Question: If $A=B$ are posets then $(A,\leq_1)$ and $(B,\leq_2)$ i.e. can it be ${\leq_1}\neq{\leq_2}$? Or it must be ${\leq_1}={\leq_2}={\leq}$?

Comment: No problem. No it can be that they have different orderings. But in the context of this question, I didn't mention it. I have added that in.

Comment: How do you go from $a \in \operatorname{maximals}(A)$ to $a\in B$?

Comment: That's not part of the argument. I used $A=B$ to obtain $a \in B$.